# IgnoreAutoIncludes does it do anything in case explicit loading is used throughout the application?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

I use explicit loading everywhere in my application, lazy loading is disabled. In this case will `IgnoreAutoIncludes()` in LINQ query will actually do anything? I would think that nothing instead of value types won't be loaded anyway for the fetched entity.